# route not working when using encoded url as upcast parameter

Tags: 8, routes

my route

```
   amu_hal.publicationsPerYear:
      path: '/publications/{year}/{url}'
      defaults:
        _controller: '\Drupal\amu_hal\Controller\AmuHalController::publicationPerYear'
        _title: 'publicationPerYear'
        year: 2016
        url: 'default url'
      requirements:
        _permission: 'access content'
```

that type of request

```
http://my_site/publications/2016/my_encoded_url
```

gives

The requested page could not be found.

and does not enter

```
   class AmuHalController extends ControllerBase {
           public function publicationPerYear($year,$url) {
```

this

```
http://my_site/publications/2016/hallo
```

does enter into my controller action

but this not:

```
 http://my_site/publications/2016/https%3A%2F%2Fmy_webservice%2Fsearch%2F%3Frows%3D5%26sort%3DproducedDate_tdate%2Bdesc%26fl%3Dtitle_s%2Cen_title_s%2Clabel_s%2Cen_label_s%2CdocType_s%2CauthIdHal_s%2ChalId_s%2CstructId_i%2Curi_s%2Ckeyword_s%2Cen_keyword_s%2CauthLastNameFirstName_s%2CjournalTitle_s%26fq%3DauthFullName_t%3A(%22M.+trump%22+OR+%22donald+trump%22)
```

Comment: As far as Drupal's concerned I think the route you're requesting is actually `/publications/2016/https:/<empty string>/etc...`. Since there's no route defined for `/publications/2016/https:` and upwards, and given that [automatically passing of extra arguments has been dropped](https://www.drupal.org/node/1827544) I'm not sure there are any options. Apart from just using a query string, of course

Comment: thanks Clive. can u explain how to modify my code to use a query string?

Comment: Looks like you got that sorted with a new question?

Comment: i cannot hide anything from u :)